# Default values for properties of C Struct

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a push function for a linked list, but the following program is causing a segmentation fault. I'm wondering a couple of things: what's the default value for properties of a struct? It seems that I have to manually set the value of `head->next` to be `NULL`. What is the default value of `head->next` then?

I believe the reason the program breaks is because in the push function, `head->next != NULL` so it then executes the line `head = head->next`, which leads me to wonder what the value of `head->next` is if it isn't `NULL`, and why this causes a segmentation fault?

```
typedef struct Node {
    struct Node *next;
    int data;
} Node;

void push(Node *head, int data);

int main()
{
    struct Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head->data = 1;

    // Works when I uncomment this line
    // head->next = NULL;

    push(head, 2);
    return 0;
}

/* Insert */
void push(Node *head, int data) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        if (head->next == NULL) {
            Node *n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            n->data = data;
            head->next = n;
            break;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Two downvotes and no comments? In an effort to help you out -- you're likely being downvoted for lack of research effort (probably?) because, as the answer below states, `reading them before assignment is undefined behavior,` which is relatively common knowledge, as any C tutorial, especially one on linked lists, probably would have told you.

Answer (score 6):

> what's the default value for properties of a struct?

C standard refers to `struct` fields as *members*, not *properties*.

Members of `struct`s in C have defined values in three situations:

- When you allocate `struct`s in static/global memory, or
- When you supply member values through an initializer, or
- You use memory allocation routine that zeroes out the memory.

In all other cases `struct` members must be *assigned* before the first use; reading them before assignment is undefined behavior.

In your situation, `struct` is allocated in dynamic memory by `malloc`. This means that its members must be assigned explicitly.

If you switch to `calloc` from `malloc`, `struct`'s memory would be zeroed out for you:

```
Node *n = calloc(1, sizeof(Node));
```

Comment: Note on terminology: The C standard refers to `struct` _members_, not _properties_. It might be a good idea to use the standard terms, as uncommon terms often cause confusion (properties of a `struct` in C context can be qualifiers or specifiers).

Comment: @Olaf That's right. I stayed with OP's terminology to make the answer easier for him to understand, but I guess it's not a bad idea to correct the terminology as well. Thanks for the comment!